# How to solve this integral with multiple variables

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int_{-1}^{-2}\int_{-1}^{-2}\int_{-1}^{-2}\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}dxdydz$

I've tried looking it up and as far as I get is that I probably need to use cylindrical coordinates but I haven't been able to solve it.

I also tried those sites that calculate them for you and give you steps but they say that they can't solve it (one says is not possible and the other says comp time exceeded).

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3197240/321264.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$I_x=\int\limits_{-1}^{-2}\int\limits_{-1}^{-2}\int\limits_{-1}^{-2}\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z=
\iiint\limits_V\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,\mathrm{d}v$$ where $V:\,\{(x,y,z)|-2\le x\le -1,-2\le y\le -1,-2\le z\le -1\}$, $\mathrm{d}v=\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z$.

Let $I_y=\iiint\limits_V\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,\mathrm{d}v$ and $I_z=\iiint\limits_V\frac{z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,\mathrm{d}v$ then it's obvious that $I_x=I_y=I_z$ because of symmethry of $V$ respective to a permutation of $x,y,z$. So
$$I_x+I_y+I_z=\iiint\limits_V\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,\mathrm{d}v=\iiint\limits_V\,\mathrm{d}v=(-2-(-1))^3=-1$$
and thus $I_x=-\frac{1}{3}$ (Thanks to Jason Helman and Integrand for mentioning the sign).

Comment: Excuse me but I don't get what do you mean by "in terms of the desired integral". Would you explain it to me please?

Comment: Suppose you somehow obtained $I_x$. Then what do you know of $I_y$ and $I_z$ if $I_x$ is already known? Can you somehow express $I_y,\,I_z$ using (=in terms of) $I_x$?

Comment: Like they summed up would be part of a whole like the integral of a constant? I don't really get it

Comment: Please see the edits -- more rigorous version of what's going on.

Comment: What do you mean by symmethry of V? How do you know that?
I realize it may be a very basic question that I should know, if that is the case please just reffer me to an online article or what should I google and I will read it thoroughly

Comment: If we take the definition of $V$ and somehow permute $x,y,z$ within it, we obtain the definition of $V$ again. Maybe proving $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$ contains similar ideas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109461/discussion-between-mrace2c-and-alexey-burdin).

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is **$-1/3$**.  The first answer has the wrong sign/answer (they put **$1/3$**) as they reversed $-1$ and $-2$ at the end, making the cube of it positive, rather than negative; it should be $(-2-(-1))^3=-1$.
(Hopefully they will soon update their answer to reflect this).

Comment: Thank you for this catch; however, this is most appropriate as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I really wanted to do a comment, but this is my first time, I don't have enough reputation to comment on other answers!!